# Generating functors with iterator behavior

Tags: c++, iterator, generator, functor

I have a question, which very likely has been asked like this before, because I think what I want is something that a considerable amount of people would want. However I could not come up with any way of expressing it that would return what I wanted in search (not google, not here). So maybe the answer here is just a single term used to describe what I mean.

What I want to implement is something that roughly does the following:

1. It can take a functor struct/class and generate a sequence of values
   for said functor based on the functor's function. It should be possible to use a stateful functor, i.e. it should be possible to instantiate a functor in state a and let it run until it is in state b, generating the range of values {f(a), f(a+1), ..., f(b)}, where f(a+1) represents the next item in the series represented by f.
2. It behaves like an iterator, i.e. it can be passed instead of an iterator e.g. to fill a vector with values.

I think the name should be generator or generating iterator, because that's what it does, but I have been very unsuccessful in finding something with that term. I have written my own implementation, but it has its issues, and I wanted to ask, if there is such a thing before putting any more effort into it.

To save you the work of pasting all the subsequent code in case you want to try this out I put it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/9Ph5el). I think after running the code it is pretty clear what it does.

My current implementation looks like this (fyi this is a shortened version, where some stuff like -- and - are missing, so yes I do implement them, and thus it can work at least as bidirectional iterator. I also have a [] function, so I thought about making it random_access.):

```
template <class F>
class generator{
public:
//typedefs required for iterator-use
typedef typename F::value_type value_type;
typedef typename F::step_type step_type;
typedef value_type * pointer;
typedef value_type & reference;
typedef typename F::size_type size_type;
typedef typename F::difference_type difference_type;
typedef std::bidirectional_iterator_tag iterator_category;

generator(value_type init, step_type step) : t(init), step(step){}

generator<F> &operator++() {
    t += step; return *this;
}

generator<F> &
operator+=(size_type n)
{
    t += n * step;
    return *this;
}

generator<F>
operator+(size_type n)
{
    return generator(*this) += n;
}

value_type operator*() const {
    return f(t);
}

value_type operator*() const {
    return f(t);
}

friend bool operator==(const generator<F> &lhs, const generator<F> &rhs){
    return lhs.t == rhs.t;
}
friend bool operator!=(const generator<F> &lhs, const generator<F> &rhs){
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}
private:
    value_type t;
    value_type step;
    F f;
};
```

I use a different template to provide the typedefs as easily as possible:

```
template <typename T>
struct simple_generator_function
{
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T step_type;
    typedef T difference_type;
    typedef size_t size_type;
};
```

Right now these two work together with a concrete "generator" like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct square_generator : public simple_generator_function<T> {

    T operator()(T t) const{
        return t * t;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    using int_sqg = generator<square_generator<int>>;
    //starting at initial value 1 take steps of size 4
    int_sqg gen(1, 1);
    //fill with all before inital + n * step
    vector<int> v(gen, gen+10);
    copy(begin(v), end(v), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ","));
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Long story short: Is there a boost or other library, which offers this in a somewhat reliable manner and what is the name of such a iterator/functor-mix in general?

EDIT 1:

I think any solution can at best be an InputIterator, because as far as I have researched it, all other iterators would have to return a reference from 
operator*(), which is out of the question in this case. Very likely, it comes down to writing a template that converts a regular functor into an InputIterator.

Status: the answers so far are good, but I have put some thought into this for quite a while before asking, and I had thought about similar solutions, so my question is not really answered. I have updated requirement 1.) to - hopefully - reflect more clearly what I want. If nothing comes of this I will probably try to refine my current code into a more stable version and put it on github.

EDIT 2 (End of Bounty):

Even though I am not entirely satisfied with the solution, boost::irange in combination with boost::transformed as ectamur suggested come closest to doing what I want, so I will give the bounty to him.

Comment: Something like [`boost::function_input_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_input_iterator.html) or [`boost::function_output_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html)?

Comment: Similar, but the function_input_iterator seems to be a pain to use. I mean I get that I can create the function by creating, e.g. a square_gen where I use bind to fix the step-size and pass that as template argument, but it seems so inconvenient, to use make_function_input_iterator all the time. Right now I can just use things like operator+, operator- and even operator[] and I would like to maintain this flexibility.

Comment: btw this can now be implemented properly with coroutines. Idk how relevant this question still is to people, so if it still is up-vote the comment and I will elaborate if it hits 5, otherwise leave the question inactive and dead.

Answer (score 5):

The Boost.Range way to solve this problem is to use the `transform` iterator adaptor:

```
auto rng = boost::irange(1, 10)
    | boost::adaptors::transformed([](int i) { return i * i; });
std::vector<int> v{rng.begin(), rng.end()};
```

Note how this separates the concerns of the transformation from the start/stop/step (optional) parameters of the input range.

Comment: Same as for Sam's answer: this solution uses iteration over a range instead of being iterable. It is a valid solution and I am using stuff like this all the time, but it is not what I was looking for (2nd criterion).

Comment: @midor ranges *are* iterable; they support `begin` and `end`. I'm not clear from your question why an iterator-only solution would be preferable.

Comment: Yes, but ranges are ranges. Any range from (1,10) takes up ten elements in memory, and you have to store these elements to later apply transform on them. What I want is to create an iterable wrapper for a functor that does the computation at the time it is de-referenced and that does not store it. When you say ranges are iterable you are mixing up two things: the range is iterable, but the range is not the function. The range is the result of the application of the function to a range. The function/functor itself cannot be iterated.

Comment: @midor I think you misunderstand how Boost.Range works. `irange` uses constant storage; it generates its results on demand. Similarly, `transformed` only performs computations when dereferenced. See e.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba1734654af2cc79 for an example.

Comment: I have looked into boost::irange in combination with adaptors and I think it is very close to what I want, but as far as I understood it can only handle built-in integer types as range-indices, and that would be a limitation I cannot live with. Implementing this kind of concept based on integers and positive integer step-sizes is considerably easier than what I am trying to get. If I got it wrong please explain, because the information I could get on irange was somewhat sparse.

Comment: @midor by "range-indices" do you mean the difference type? If so that has to be an integral type (though not necessarily a built-in integer type) to allow iteration of a range via `++` to make sense. It doesn't make sense to offset an iterator by e.g. a floating-point value, because the result would not be reachable from the original iterator.

Comment: The point is that you will basically create fun(i), fun(i+1), ... fun(n), with the irange and transform, because the range can only be composed of elements of a type implementing the Integer concept. Of course the distance between two sequence elements must have integral distance - representing the distance between the sequence indices -, but overloading operator++ and iterating a sequence with it, i.e.  *functor++ may be considerably cheaper, because construction of the single sequence elements may be much more expensive than an increment on an existing sequence element.

Comment: @midor `transform` only evaluates `fun(i + 1)` if and when you indirect the 2nd range element i.e. `*++rng.begin()`. I don't see how that could possibly be made more efficient. Similarly, an `irange` iterator stores its current sequence value so will be incremented inplace by `++`.

Comment: I am perfectly aware of that. Consider any function with a behaviour anything similar to: f(0) = x_0, f(1) = x_1 + f(0), ..., f(n)  = x_n + f(n-1) + ... + f(0). Obviously computing f(1), f(2), ... f(n) is more expensive than doing an incremental computation. I aware that you can improve the performance in this example with dynamic programming in the functor applying f(), but this box is too small to fit my explanation of an example where it cannot be applied (I tried).

Comment: @midor ah yes, that wouldn't work with irange especially as it can't be random access (there's no way from f(i) to f(j) without traversing the intermediate results). I'd be inclined to calculate that range transformed from an intermediate range over a vector of the previous f(i); I'm pretty sure boost.range would allow you to do that without copying.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, we can just write our own iterator:

```
template <typename F, typename Value>
class func_iterator
: std::iterator<
    std::random_access_iterator_tag,
    typename std::result_of<F(Value)>::type,
    Value,
    typename std::result_of<F(Value)>::type,
    typename std::result_of<F(Value)>::type>
{ .. };
```

This iterator needs three things: a function (`F f`), the current value and the step (`Value value, step`). Dereferencing will calculate the value of the function each time:

```
using T = typename std::result_of<F(Value)>::type;
T operator*() { return f(value); }
```

Selected iterating functions (omitting postfix since they look the same):

```
func_iterator& operator++() {
    value += step;
    return *this;
}

func_iterator& operator--() {
    value -= step;
    return *this;
}

func_iterator operator+(Value amt) {
    return func_iterator{f, value + amt * step, step};
}
```

Difference between iterators (for `std::distance`) and equality:

```
Value operator-(const func_iterator& rhs) {
    assert(step == rhs.step);
    return (value - rhs.value) / step;
}

bool operator==(const func_iterator& rhs) {
    return value == rhs.value && step == rhs.step;
}
```

And finally a function to make an iterator for us:

```
template <typename F, typename Value>
func_iterator<F, Value> make_func_iterator(F f, Value v, Value s = 1) {
    return func_iterator<F, Value>{f, v, s};
}
```

Putting that together, I can do something like:

```
auto sq_it = make_func_iterator([](int x){return x*x;}, 1);
std::vector<int> squares{sq_it, sq_it + 10}; // v now holds {1, 4, 9, 16, ..., 100}
```

Or just:

```
// get a bunch of even numbers, complicatedly:
auto ident = make_func_iterator([](int x){return x;}, 2, 2);
std::vector<int> evens{ident, ident+200}; // holds {2, 4, ..., 400}
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. What you are suggesting is what I have right now. However there are some issues with it, e.g. that operator* is usually expected to return a reference for all iterators but InputIterators. Also it does not work nicely with functions that do not take any arguments, i.e. stateless functions. In my latest implementation I have moved the state to the functor itself, just fyi.

Comment: @midor It doesn't have to return a reference - that's just convention - and it's easier to reason about the iterator if you do it this way. Also it works plenty nice with stateless functions, just wrap it in a lambda that ignores its argument.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this could be called *tabulation*. If so, what do you thing about the following interface?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

#include "tabulate.hpp"

template<typename T>
void show(const T& data) {
  for(const auto & x: data) std::cout << x << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  auto fun = [](double x) { return 2.0 * x; };

  std::vector<double> x  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  std::cout << "using range-for" << std::endl;
  for(const auto & fx : tabulate(fun, x.begin(), x.end())) {
    std::cout << fx << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << "initializing a vector" << std::endl;
  auto init = tabulate(fun, x.begin(), x.end());
  std::vector<double> values(init.begin(), init.end());
  show(values);

  std::cout << "automatic construction of vector" << std::endl;
  auto in_vector = make_tabulation<std::vector<double>>(fun, x);
  show(in_vector);

  std::cout << "automatic construction of list" << std::endl;
  auto in_list   = make_tabulation<std::list<double>>(fun, x);
  show(in_list);
}
```

Which is implemented by the following header:

```
#pragma once
#include <iterator>

template<typename Fun,
         typename InputIt,
         typename T = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type
         >
class tabulate_iterator

    : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, T> {

 public:

  tabulate_iterator()
      : m_is_valid(false) { }

  tabulate_iterator(Fun& fun, InputIt beg, InputIt end)
      : m_fun(&fun),
        m_beg(beg),
        m_end(end),
        m_is_valid(beg != end) {
    this->read();
  }

  const T& operator*() const {
    return m_current;
  }

  const T* operator->() const {
    return &(operator*());
  }

  tabulate_iterator& operator++() {
    this->read();
    return *this;
  }

  tabulate_iterator operator++(int) {
    auto tmp = *this;
    this->read();
    return tmp;
  }

  bool equals(const tabulate_iterator& other) const {
    return ((m_is_valid == other.m_is_valid) and
            (not m_is_valid));
  }

  bool operator==(const tabulate_iterator& other) const {
    return this->equals(other);
  }

  bool operator!=(const tabulate_iterator& other) const {
    return not this->equals(other);
  }

 private:

  void read() {
    if(m_is_valid and m_beg != m_end) {
      m_current = (*m_fun)(*m_beg++);
    } else {
      m_is_valid = false;
    }
  }

  T       m_current;
  Fun*    m_fun;
  InputIt m_beg;
  InputIt m_end;
  bool    m_is_valid;

};

template<typename Fun,
         typename InputIt,
         typename T = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type
         >
class tabulate_range {

 public:

  tabulate_iterator<Fun, InputIt, T> begin() const {
    return m_it;
  }

  tabulate_iterator<Fun, InputIt, T> end() const {
    return m_it_end;
  }

 private:

  template<typename Fun_, typename InputIt_, typename T_>
  friend tabulate_range<Fun_, InputIt_, T_> tabulate(Fun_, InputIt_, InputIt_);

  tabulate_range(Fun fun, InputIt beg, InputIt end)
      : m_it(fun, beg, end),
        m_it_end() { }

  tabulate_iterator<Fun, InputIt, T> m_it;
  tabulate_iterator<Fun, InputIt, T> m_it_end;
};

template<typename Fun,
         typename InputIt,
         typename T = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type
         >
tabulate_range<Fun, InputIt, T> tabulate(Fun fun, InputIt beg, InputIt end) {
  return tabulate_range<Fun, InputIt, T>(fun, beg, end);
}

template<typename OutContainer, typename Fun, typename InContainer>
OutContainer make_tabulation(Fun fun, const InContainer& x) {
  auto init = tabulate(fun, x.begin(), x.end());
  return OutContainer(init.begin(), init.end());
}
```

Some caveats: I just cracked this code in the spur of the moment, so bugs are likely; take this as a proof of concept.

Compilation (GCC 4.8.2/Linux;  ICC 14.0.2 20140120/Linux):

```
{CXX} tabulate.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out
using range-for
2
4
6
8
10
initializing a vector
2 4 6 8 10
automatic construction of vector
2 4 6 8 10
automatic construction of list
2 4 6 8 10
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you obviously put quite a bit of effort into your solution. There are two things I am not entirely sure about: first, why do you think it should be called tabulate? Second, this seems to do something that I usually do with std::transform, because it takes an input-container and generates an output-container by applying a function to it. My idea behind this whole thing was, that I don't want to create the input-container, and I possibly don't even want to create the output-container, but just a series of results, i.e the object when passed to a function is a command pat. .

Answer (score 0):

The C++ library already offers some algorithms that implement most of the functionality you're trying to do on your own. I think it's better for you to adapt your template so that it would work seamlessly with the C++ library, instead.

I'm thinking specifically of `std::generate()`.

So, you take what you're planning to do in your step #1, but replace step #2 with implementing an `operator()` that returns the next value in the sequence.

Then, you can let `std::generate`() take care of populating an actual sequence with your values.

Comment: I am familiar with std::generate() and somewhat obviously this is where I started out, but std::generate iterates over something, whereas I want something iterable.