# How to avoid code duplication when iterating over either a vector<int> or numeric range?

Tags: c++, iterator, range, code-duplication

I need to execute rather complex piece of code in the loop, but the loop is either over vector or over numeric range of integers. The decision about the loop type is made on run time:

```
if(!int_vector_provided){
   for(int i=0;i<N;++i){ // iterate over a numeric range
      // complex code depending on i
   }
} else {
   for(int i: int_vector){ // iterate over a vector
      // the same complex code
   }
}
```

The problem is that "complex code" is hard to refactor as a function since it depends on many local and global variables. It it also undesirable to make this code a capturing lambda, since this part is performance-critical.
If numeric range is used than it is usually very large (millions), so it is very inefficient to create a vector of successive numbers of this size.

What I need in fact is a pair of iterators, which could be assigned to either begin/end of the vector or begin/end of the numeric range. Something like:

```
SomeCleverIterator b,e;

if(int_vector_provided){
   b = int_vector.begin();
   e = int_vector.end();  
} else {
   // Iterators to numeric range
   // may be boost::counting_range(0,N) ???
   // but how to make boost::range iterators and 
   // to vector<int>::iterator convertible to the same type??
   b = ???;
   e = ???;
}

for(SomeCleverIterator it=b;it!=e;it++){
      // complex code
}
```

I tried to play with `boost::counting_range` but its iterators are not convertible to `vector<int>::iterator` so it doesn't help.

The only way which I see it to create a custom class template with iterators and to instantiate it explicitly for vector and for the pair of integers, but this looks like an overkill for such "trivial" problem.

Is there any better way?

Comment: Why not just iterate over the vector as numeric range [0, size())? Also be careful if you change performance critical code like this. moving the if/else into the loop likely interacts with branch-prediction and can have a negative performance impact.

Comment: @midor because vector may contain any non-successive integers like {1,100,150,1000}

Comment: XY problem. Instead of `int_vector_provided` there should be 2 separate functions, and the "complex code" part should be extracted into a helper inline function. Or provide a [mcve] explaining your situation in detail.

Comment: This reads like a classic XY problem. If you have two loops, in the same function, that have the same body, then refactoring to place the "complex code" in a function is trivial.    If the "complex code" depends on variables IN your caller, pass them as arguments (or, worst case, create a struct containing a set of references to them, and pass that as an argument).   If the "complex code" depends on statics declared before your caller, then placing a new function immediately above will have visibility of the same statics.

Comment: You already realized what is the actual problem. Global variables will always bite you on the long run. Better don't delay it further and fix that.

Answer (score 3):

As you have the same code with different types, that calls for templates.

And as it will only be used in that one function, a generic lambda is most expedient:

```
auto f = [&](auto&& range) {
    for (int i : range) {
        // complex code depending on i
    }
};
if (int_vector_provided)
    f(int_vector);
else
    f(std::ranges::iota_view(0, N));
```

I also used C++20 [`std::ranges::iota_view`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view).

Of course, this might also be a case of flag-envy, in which case you should just split the interface into two different functions instead, possibly backed by a common implementation.

Also, global state should be minimized, especially the mutable kind.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that "complex code" is hard to refactor as a function since it depends on many local and global variables.

That definitely sounds like a reason why you *should* refactor this code.

> It it also undesirable to make this code a capturing lambda, since this part is performance-critical.

Have you measured that a capturing lambda is less performant? I would think that it should be about as fast as the code directly and it would definitely be the easiest solution.

That being said, I think the key to your problem is polymorphism. Since you only need two different types being handled, I would recommend looking at `std::variant`. You would use `std:: variant<typename std::vector<int>::iterator, int>` and do all the operations by visitors.

**Edit:** 
A low-tech solution:

```cpp
int index = 0;
const int end = int_vector_provided ? int_vector.size() : N;
for(; index < end; ++index) {
    int to_use = int_vector_provided ? vector[index] : index;
    // Do calculations with to_use
}
```

This adds extraneous bool checks on `int_vector_provided` but I would think the optimizer will work pretty well on that if it is `const` (I would think that the `const` makes here a significant difference concerning performance).

Comment: Capturing lambda decreases a performance in this case. Not very critical but measurable. I'd like to avoid it.
One more point against using variant and visitors is that the code itself is complex (this is a really non-trivial numerical code) thus I'd like to minimize the "boilerplate" if possible.

Comment: The boilerplate with `variant` would not be very big. You have 3 visitors, one for the comparison, one for the increment (both of them are trivial) and one for dereferencing the iterator. After that you have an int in both cases and exactly the same code afterwards.

Comment: @yesint I added a very low-tech solution.

Answer (score 1):

Reminds me of a more general [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263134/generating-functors-with-iterator-behavior) I once asked on iteration/generators. There wasn't really any satisfactory general satisfactory solution until C++20. Nowadays you can probably do it with coroutines that yield the next element and erase their type, but I haven't coded that out yet.

Anyway, in your case the problem in the code boils down to two core points:

1. you have so much context that you can't factor out a function
2. you cannot have a variable that can hold both iterators because the iterator form a vector is an iterator

You can iterate over both using index-based iteration, but you will have to decide in every iteration, if you use `i`, or `v[i]`. Hoisting out the condition is likely still faster.

There is also a complicated solution to this, which is to implement an iterator-wrapper that erases the type of the iterator, but unless you have something like this already available, I would advise to not go for that solution, because it will be complex, hard to get right, and probably disproportionate.

You haven't posted context, so I can't tell to what extent that's possible, but I feel like the best advice I can give you is to refactor the rest of the code before you touch on this issue. It's likely that the complexity of the context makes this duplication so painful, rather than the duplication itself. Hoisting out such a check is a common optimization, that isn't always detrimental to maintainability/readability.

Comment: Yes, "generators", like in Python, would solve such problems once and forever. However, pragmatic solution in my case is probably to refactor the mess in the loop and make it a function or a callable class.